Pinia state loosing reactivity when used in an object?
Trying to wrap my head around reactivity when it comes to states from a Pinia store.
I have the following store (@/stores/settings.js):
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useSettings = defineStore('Settings', {
  state: () => ({
    useDarkTheme: false
  }),
  persist: true
})

And the following component (App.vue):
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useSettings } from '@/stores/settings'

const settings = useSettings()
const { useDarkTheme } = storeToRefs(settings)

let appClasses = ref({
  'test-class': true,
  'dark-theme': useDarkTheme.value
})
</script>

<template>
  <div class="app-wrapper" :class="appClasses">
    <div class="app-content" :class="useDarkTheme ? 'đark' : 'light'">
            /* ... */
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

On the app-content div, useDarkTheme is reactive: whenever its value changes in the store, the class switches betwenn "light" and "dark". No need to reload the app.
However when used in the appClasses object, useDarkTheme seems to loose its reativity. The "dark-theme" class is applied (or not) based on the value stored in Pinia when the component is loaded, but then it isn't updated to reflect the change that occurs in the store (until the component is loaded again, e.g. by reloading the app). The same is true if I use "reactive" instead of "ref".
What am I missing here?

What about 'dark-theme': useDarkTheme,

@chiliNUT oh you're right! Thanks for the suggestion!

Turns out I should have used useDarkTheme instead of useDarkTheme.value in my object:
let appClasses = ref({
  'test-class': true,
  'dark-theme': useDarkTheme
})

Thanks to @chiliNUT for the tip!

Use computed instead of ref.
let appClasses = computed(()=>{
return {
  'test-class': true,
  'dark-theme': useDarkTheme.value
}
})


Thanks, this also work indeed. It's a bit more convoluted than the other proposed solution though. Any reason why this one would be preferable?

Yes,this is a bit more convoluted than the answer above, but it's easier to understand.,some people don't really understand when to add .value to a ref and when to omit it.
